# Why the infinite union of a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

A measure, $\mu$, and one of it's underlying components, the $\sigma$-algebra, where $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ if:

- $\emptyset \in S$
- if $E \in S$ then $E' \in S$
- if $E_1, E_2...$ is a sequence of elements of $S$, then $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k \in S$

And a measure $\mu$ on $(X,S)$ is a function $ \mu: S \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ such that $\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ and:

$ \mu ( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_k ) = \Sigma_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_k) $
for every disjoint sequence $E_1, E_2...$ on $S$.

Further, understanding that $E_k$ can be finite while having infinite, non-distinct union on $S$, my question is:

**Do we provide for the $\sigma$-algebra's union on $E_k$ so that, in some sense, we have an arbitrary understanding of the relation of elements over which we are measuring?**

Comment: If you look up proofs of measurability (or even more specifically, the Borel classification) of a lot of common constructions -- convergence set of a sequence of functions, every open set is a countable union of closed sets (and "open", "closed" can be switched), set of points where the values of a function is greater than some specified number, set of points where a function has a positive derivative, etc. -- you'll see countably infinite unions and countably infinite intersections showing up. The later chapters of your textbook should show many instances of these operations.

Answer (score 0):

One *could* repeat the same definition, but use a) only finite unions or b) arbitrary unions instead of countable unions. However, this would define different concepts.

If we only demand that $S$ contains the empty set, is closed under complements, and closed under finite union (or equivalently: binary union), then we would also consider the set of all finite or cofinite sets as "sigma-algebra". This is not what we need for measure theory. In particular, we cannot even define $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)$ because in general $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k$ is not in the "sigma-algebra".

If more stronger, we demand that $S$ contains the empty set, is closed under complements, and closed under arbitrary union, then this would severely restrict the concept of "sigma-algebra". For example, every such "sigma-algebra" that contains all singletons must be the full power set of $X$! And why would we ask our algebras to be closed under arbitrary unions when the thing we aim for, the definition of a measure, cannot make use of arbitrary unions: If we wanted to have $\mu(\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i)=\sum_{i\in I}\mu(E_i)$ to make sense for for larger-than-countable unions, then we better have $\mu(E_i)$ for all but countably many $E_i$ in the sum or must live with infinite measure for very many sets.

So (at least with hindsight, given the usefulness of measures) the countable-union definition is the most adequate one. If you look carefully, we might be a bit more strict and only demand closure under countable *disjoint* union (after all, only countable *disjoint* unions are used in the definition of measures). However, this would change nothing as "closed under countable union" and "closed under countable disjoint union" can readily be shown to be equivalent if one has the other two axioms (empty set and closed under complement).